# Oracle Trigger gets the wrong values, what have i done wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, triggers

I tried to create a trigger to get the purchase price(preco_custo) when the type of the movimentation is a purchase(E) and to get the sales price (preco_venda) when its a sale(S). But it is getting the purchase price, no matter what type it is. Can somebody explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER P_CUSTO
BEFORE INSERT ON FRANCISCO.MOVIMENTACAO
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   V_COUNT      PLS_INTEGER                := NULL;
   V_TIPO       FRANCISCO.MOVIMENTACAO.TIPO%TYPE      := NULL;
   V_PCUSTO     FRANCISCO.PRODUTOS.PRECO_CUSTO%TYPE   := NULL;
   V_PVENDA     FRANCISCO.PRODUTOS.PRECO_VENDA%TYPE   := NULL;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(ROWNUM), NVL(MAX(TIPO),'E')
   INTO V_COUNT, V_TIPO
   FROM FRANCISCO.MOVIMENTACAO
   WHERE ID = :New.ID;

   SELECT COUNT(ROWNUM), NVL(MAX(PRECO_CUSTO),0), NVL(MAX(PRECO_VENDA),0)
   INTO V_COUNT, V_PCUSTO, V_PVENDA
   FROM FRANCISCO.PRODUTOS
   WHERE ID = :New.ID_PRODUTO;

   IF UPPER(V_TIPO) = 'E' THEN
     :New.CUSTO_UNITARIO := V_PCUSTO;
   ELSE 
      :New.CUSTO_UNITARIO := V_PVENDA;
   END IF; 
END;
/
```

And how, after fixing this trigger, i use the value returned in a funcion?

Comment: I cannot see the relationship between what you want to do and the code in the trigger.  Why are you counting `rownum`?  What is the relationship between the two tables?  Why are you running two queries instead of joining the table together?

Comment: one table is to register the products, and the other to register the sales/purchases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `NEW` values which are available in the trigger, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER P_CUSTO
   BEFORE INSERT ON FRANCISCO.MOVIMENTACAO
   REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   V_COUNT      PLS_INTEGER                           := NULL;
   V_PCUSTO     FRANCISCO.PRODUTOS.PRECO_CUSTO%TYPE   := NULL;
   V_PVENDA     FRANCISCO.PRODUTOS.PRECO_VENDA%TYPE   := NULL;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(ROWNUM), NVL(MAX(PRECO_CUSTO),0), NVL(MAX(PRECO_VENDA),0)
   INTO V_COUNT, V_PCUSTO, V_PVENDA
   FROM FRANCISCO.PRODUTOS
   WHERE ID = :New.ID_PRODUTO;

   IF UPPER(:NEW.TIPO) = 'E' THEN
      :New.CUSTO_UNITARIO := V_PCUSTO;
   ELSE 
      :New.CUSTO_UNITARIO := V_PVENDA;
   END IF; 
END;
```

I'm surprised the original version of the trigger didn't throw an ORA-04091 when the SELECT against FRANCISCO.MOVIMENTICAO was executed.

Share and enjoy.